# Can't access dotnet's environment variable via build target

Tags: .net, msbuild

I'm trying to access the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable inside a `Target`'s `Build` event.

The `.csproj` looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="MyPostBuild" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <Exec Command="echo Operating System: $(OS)"/>
        <Exec Command="echo ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: $(ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT)"/>
    </Target>

</Project>
```

The launchSettings.json contain the environment variable:

```
"profiles": {
    "DemoProject": {
        "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
    }
}
```

It outputs the `$(OS)` very well but it does not prints the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`:

> Operating System Windows_NT

> ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT:

My question is **how to access the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` value within a `Build` event** in order to make the build event run only with a specific condition like this:

```
<Target Name="MyPostBuild" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition="'$(ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT)' == 'Development'">
    Do something
</Target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`launchSettings.json` is used when you run your application. The values from there are not available in compile time. That's why you get an empty string when trying to read the value.

What you could do instead is to do a condition based on one of the values that [are available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2022) like `Configuration`.

```
'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'
```